# Spatial Join problems in ArcGIS 10.1 - intersect polygon and lines

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1, line, spatial-join

1. I have hurricane tracks (Lines) and Florida county boundary (polygon) and I want to extract only those hurricane tracks that intersect Florida.
2. In ArcMap 10.0 I used Spatial Join (from Analysis/Overlay) to join the hurricane tracks and Florida polygon map. This created a new shp file of only those tracks that intersected Florida. Importantly it kept the entire length of each of the hurricane track lines that intersected Florida.
3. I have tried repeating this in ArcMap 10.1 using Spatial Join and while it seems to intersect the hurricane tracks with Florida okay - the new shp file does not have the entire length for each of the hurricane tracks - only short bits of lines outside the Florida polygon boundary.

Can anyone provide guidance on why this may be the case - it is critical for this exercise to extract the those hurricane tracks intersecting Florida polygon but we need the entire length of each of the tracks for each of these hurricanes.

Comment: Have you tried Intersect and gotten the same results?

Comment: I would try Select by location and then make a dataset from the selected features. It might not work if each track consists of multiple parts, however.

Comment: Wouldn´t it be easier to simply use a "Select by Location" on the hurricane tracks and select those that "intersect" Florida? You can then export the selection as a new shapefile (Right-Click Layer --> Data --> Export Data)

Comment: you should do an intersect first to break the line at the county boundaries.

Comment: if you need the attributes of the county on the path line then a spatial join will do that.

Comment: Sorry correction the ArcMap version was 10 SP 2. I also tried the join and select by locaiton but got the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eyeball the data, make sure the "short bits of lines outside the Florida" are not a parts of multipart features which interesect Florida.

after that you'd want to rule out the input data being bad.

1. make copies of both your input datasets
2. Run [RepairGeometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Repair_Geometry/00170000003v000000/) on both
3. make sure both have correct coordinate system defined
4. re-run SpatialJoin